# Action of correspondences on motivic cohomology sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, motivic-cohomology

Writing $\mathcal{H}^a(\mathbb{Z}(b))$ for the Zariski sheaf of motivic cohomology groups, there is a hypercohomology/descent spectral sequence
$$ H^p(X,\mathcal{H}^q(\mathbb{Z}(n))) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X, \mathbb{Z}(n)).$$
Motivic cohomology groups, i.e. the target of this sequence, take actions of correspondences factoring through rational equivalence. I was wondering if the same was true for the groups $H^p(X,\mathcal{H}^q(\mathbb{Z}(n)))$ - it seems like you could proceed to defining such an action by very similar means, and I'd expect the resulting action to (a) also factor through rational equivalence, and (b) be compatible with the spectral sequence. Is this true, and if so, is it written down somewhere?